# Indexing separate survival curves

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I would like to plot Kaplan-Meier survival estimates for each of two groups in ggplot.

To do so requires getting a separate survival curve for each group. The `survfit` function in the `survival` package splits the nicely but I don't know how to index the separate plots to work on them.

Here is sample data:

```
rearrest<-read.table("http://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/examples/alda/rearrest.csv", sep=",", header=T)
```

This is the curve ungrouped

```
(sCurve <- summary(arr1 <- survfit(Surv(months, abs(censor-1))~1, data = rearrest)))
```

It is easy to index elements within this, for example

```
sCurve$n.event
```

When I fit the same thing except this time grouped according to the value of the `personal` variable I get two nice survival curve objects ready to go.

```
(sCurveA <- summary(arr1 <- survfit(Surv(months, abs(censor-1))~personal, data = rearrest)))
```

One object is labelled `personal=0` and the other `personal=1`. I have tried indexing with `$`, `[]`, `[[]]` both with number-type indexes and named-, all to no avail.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sCurveA$strata provides the grouping variable as a vector. You can pull out the key pieces and throw them into a data.frame for ggplot.

```
df = data.frame(Time = sCurveA$time,
                Survival = sCurveA$surv,
                Strata = sCurveA$strata)

ggplot(df, aes(Time, Survival, col = Strata)) +
  geom_line()
```